# Where does start.log come from?

Tags: logging, solr, jetty

I am running solr 4.10.3 on jetty and keep seeing a start.log file show up in the home directory of the user I'm running solr as and can't figure out where it's coming from. I have log4j working and it logs correct to the location I specified but this appears to be a spurious duplicate log that I can't figure out how to make go away. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not really a programming question.

Thats an intermediate, system level, log that the shell startup of jetty creates to log any fundamental jetty startup issues.

This logs events during the period of time between the request to startup jetty, and when jetty finally does startup (at which point normal java logging takes over)

Comment: Point taken. I'm new the stackoverflow and have seen similar questions being asked so I assumed it was legit but realize it's off topic after review the guidelines.